# Files missing after doing disk repair

Tags: macos, mac, hard-drive, disk-utility

I have an NTFS external disk,

And I followed a stupid tutorial, it told me to repair my disk then I can delete the 'un-deletable' files in the NTFS external disk.

However, When I done the repair-disk, the files on the disk were missing.

But it seems all the files are still existing on the disk,

But couldn't be seen on OSX and Windows 7 (I used the parallel to inspect the disk)

How could I recovery the data on the disk, thanks T_T

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I experienced this exact problem yesterday. I fixed it by putting the ntfs drive onto a PC and searching for the files. They had all just been moved, not deleted--very strange. Also, running a disk error check in windows after to clean up any straggling issues.